# Pug templates with Node express - Issues with POST

Tags: pug

Good evening, I am currently simply looking to learn Node and creating a small project. I am having a problem, that I can't quite seem to solve. I have an express backend, which contains routes, these routes work fine in postman, however when incorporated via the pug template, the details from the form do not seem to go through. 
It is as though pug template is not collecting the attributes from the form, and it sends through the validation error 'Must require first name etc'. This is also my first time using PUG, so any help (or perhaps a pointer to stupidity) would be hugely appreciated.

For Routes:

```
//Register new user
router.post('/register', function(req,res,next){
    user.create(req.body).then(function(user){
        res.send(user); //new instance and save
    }).catch(next);
});
```

For PUG template:

```
extends layout
block content
      h1 Sign Up
      form#addUser(name="adduser",action='api/register', method='POST')
        label(for='firstName') First Name
        input#users.firstName(type='text' placeholder='firstName' name='firstName')
        div.form-group
          label(for='lastName') Last Name
          input#users.lastName(type='text' placeholder='lastName' name='lastName')
          div.form-group
            label(for='userName') UserName
            input#users.userName(type='text' placeholder='userName' name='userName')
          div.form-group
            label(for='password') Password
            input#users.password(type='password' placeholder='password' name='password')
          div.form-group
            label(for='email') Email
            input#users.email(type='text' placeholder='email' name='email')
        div.form-group
          label(for='jobTitle') Job Title
          input#users.jobTitle(type='text' placeholder='jobTitle' name='jobTitle')
        button(type='submit', value='add') SignUp
```

User Model:

```
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required:[true, "Username is required"]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password is required"]
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email is required"]
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, "Name field is required"]
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Name field is required"]
    },
    jobTitle :{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Position is required"]
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Error output:

> "users validation failed: jobTitle: Position is required, lastName: Name field is required, firstName: Name field is required, email: Email is required, password: Password is required, userName: Username is required"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sequelize to store your data? Try matching your form inputs with your user model to something like this:

```
form
 userName
 password
 email
 firstName
 lastName
 jobTitle
```

Also, is your router connected to your controller?